# EASY68k Trap task #12 Echo

Tags: 68000, easy68k

Just a simple question. When looking up Trap Tasks in the help file, Trap task #12 is different in the sense that it gives you an option to turn off the keyboard "echo". But it doesn't explain what an "echo" is.

My questions are:

1. What is a keyboard echo
2. What application would this trap task be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard echo means that when the user is providing input via the keyboard, the characters that he/she types will be displayed as they are typed (they are *echoed*).

The application of that trap task would be if you don't want the input to be echoed. If you have no such use-case in your program then you simply don't need that trap task.